# Files/Folder are shown in GUI but not in Terminal

Tags: command-line, gnome, mount, filesystem

Fairly new to Linux and I'm already having problems. When I open my drive from GUI, I see some files and folders there but when I try to `ls` on the terminal; it only shows two folders. `ls /media/user/drive` only shows two folders, where if I access same drive on GUI it shows me others files/folders I have.

I opened that window on the terminal by right-clicking and it showed me the path `/mnt/22E688864902EA02$` but I'm trying to access my files through `/media` where my samba share is also done.
I did some research on `mnt` and `/media` but I didn't find anything that helped me to solve my issues. I need all files to be shown on /media so I can access them on other devices through sambashare.

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
GNOME : 42.5

[image]